# Eclipse Project with Lucene Library

Tags: eclipse, jar, lucene

Hello I have tried all the mentioned solutions, but still no progress.

I am making a project that requieres Apache Lucene lib.

I create a new standard java project in eclipse.

Then right click on the project -> build path -> configure build path -> add external jar

-> locate my recently downloaded lucene-4.6.0.zip file -> ok -> ok

The library is included in the project as a Referenced library.

But when i try to import a package it can not find it. When I explore the library within eclipse all the packages are white.

I have tried to add the library as a folder. The same.

But if I add the jar files from the unpacked lucene-4.6.0.zip one by one it is okey with no errors.

Please assist me, I know that it is something stupid, but it's very annoying and time-spending.

Thank you

Comment: So what is wrong with adding jar files to your project? Ideally I would use ant or maven approach for doing my builds.

Comment: I need very much jars and i cannot add them 1 by 1. Furthermore I can't be always sure which .jar I need and because they are dozens, it's a bit hard to find it.